# Set same value for sibling component's select

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Using v-for, I am looping through a component. The component is for each client. In this component, I have same form for each client and when a select value is selected for the first component (client 1), I want to select this value for every client.

Do I need to pass the data to the root and create a single source of truth variable?

I tried setting up a basic version:

```
<div id="app">
  <my-comp v-for="x in 2" v-bind:val="x"></my-comp>
</div>


Vue.component('my-comp', {
   props: ['val'],

   template: `
    <div>
        <div>
          <label>Status</label>
          <select :data-client="val" @change="statusChanged">
              <option selected="" disabled="" value="0"></option>
              <option value="xxx">Xxx</option>
              <option value="yyy">Yyy</option>
              <option value="zzz">Zzz</option>
           </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    `,

   methods: {
     statusChanged(e) {
          var client = e.target.getAttribute('data-client')
          if (client == 1) {
            alert('set same value for client 2')
          }
     }
   }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w53164t2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I considered a little bit after my original answer and have come up with something I think is a little bit more real world than the example fiddle provided in the original question; specifically it is easy to make all the selects reflect the same value if they are all using the same source value, however I expect in a real world scenario each component would be independently bound to a single client. Each client would want their individual value to change, with the one caveat that if a "master" client changed, then all non-master clients should change to the master client's value.

To that end, this might be a case where I think a component specific bus is appropriate. The master would emit an event when *it's* value changed and the the other clients would set their value with respect to the master.

```js
console.clear()

const MyCompBus = new Vue()

Vue.component('my-comp', {
  props: ['val', 'master'],
  computed:{
    selected:{
      get(){return this.val},
      set(v){
       this.$emit('update:val', v)
       if (this.master)
         MyCompBus.$emit("master-updated", v)
     }
    }
  },
  methods:{
   onMasterUpdated(newMasterValue){
      if (this.master) return
      this.selected = newMasterValue
    }
  },
  created(){
   MyCompBus.$on('master-updated', this.onMasterUpdated)
  },
  beforeDestroy(){
   MyCompBus.$off('master-updated', this.onMasterUpdated)
  },
  template: `
  <div>
      <div>
        <label>Status</label>
        <select v-model="selected">
          <option selected="" disabled="" value="0"></option>
          <option value="xxx">Xxx</option>
          <option value="yyy">Yyy</option>
          <option value="zzz">Zzz</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    masterValue: null,
    clients:[
      {id: 1, selectedValue: null, master: true},
      {id: 2, selectedValue: null},
      {id: 3, selectedValue: null},
      {id: 4, selectedValue: null},
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-comp v-for="client in clients" 
           :val.sync="client.selectedValue" 
           :master="client.master" 
           :key="client.id">
  </my-comp>
  {{clients}}
</div>
```

**Original Answer**

Bind them all to the same value using `v-model`.

```
Vue.component('my-comp', {
  props: ['value'],
  computed:{
    selected:{
      get(){return this.value},
      set(v){this.$emit('input', v)}
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>Status</label>
        <select v-model="selected">
          <option selected="" disabled="" value="0"></option>
          <option value="xxx">Xxx</option>
          <option value="yyy">Yyy</option>
          <option value="zzz">Zzz</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

And in the template:

```
<my-comp v-for="x in 2" v-model="selectedValue" :key="x"></my-comp>
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w53164t2/1/).

If you want to stick with `val` as the property you can use `.sync` instead.

```
Vue.component('my-comp', {
  props: ['val'],
  computed:{
    selected:{
      get(){return this.val},
      set(v){this.$emit('update:val', v)}
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>Status</label>
        <select v-model="selected">
          <option selected="" disabled="" value="0"></option>
          <option value="xxx">Xxx</option>
          <option value="yyy">Yyy</option>
          <option value="zzz">Zzz</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

And in the template:

```
<my-comp v-for="x in 2" :val.sync="selectedValue" :key="x"></my-comp>
```

Example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w53164t2/2/).

If you want just one of them designated as a "master" select, then add a property that does so.

```
Vue.component('my-comp', {
  props: ['val', 'master'],
  computed:{
    selected:{
      get(){return this.val},
      set(v){if (this.master) this.$emit('update:val', v)}
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>Status</label>
        <select v-model="selected">
          <option selected="" disabled="" value="0"></option>
          <option value="xxx">Xxx</option>
          <option value="yyy">Yyy</option>
          <option value="zzz">Zzz</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

And in the template:

```
<my-comp v-for="x in 5" :val.sync="selectedValue" :master="1 == x" :key="x"></my-comp>
```

Example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w53164t2/4/).

Comment: Thanks. But I wanted something a bit different. I want only the first one to set others, and nothing to happen when second one changes. So not exactly they are both linked together, but client 1 changes for client 2

Comment: @senty Then use Bert's second example, but only use `.sync` on the first component. https://jsfiddle.net/w53164t2/5/

Comment: @senty I added yet *another* possible solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for variety of answers! I have a question though, what if I want to use multiple words instead of `val` in `:val.sync` such as `:hello-world:sync` ?

Comment: @senty A component can sync as many properties as needed. But if you end up with a large number of them you may want to consider using an object.